# Mysql equivalent of Vertica 'Interval' data type

Tags: mysql, vertica

I am trying migrate a table from Vertica to Mysql.
I noticed that my table has a Vertica datatype [interval](http://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/9255.htm).

The column details state that data sub type is `Interval Day to Second`

A sample data looks like `0 00:49:51.267000`

I was wondering if there was a mysql equivalent, if not what could be the best possible match to store the data

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of moving to MySQL is?

Comment: Let's just say I am trying to mimic some data on mysql cause I don't want to mess with live data

Comment: You're not allowed to just copy the data within Vertica?

Comment: For now I am not allowed to

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent that I know of.

I would just store it in a varchar() by the looks of that character string.

However, if you want to investigate further and see what other data types are available to you here is a good place to start [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TIME(6)` type and load it with a `VARCHAR` version of the interval.  You then would be able to do queries like:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(field) FROM TABLE;

SELECT MICROSECOND(field) FROM TABLE;
```

Just depends I guess on what you are trying to do with it.